# Create VSCode extension using Flutter

Tags: flutter, vscode-extensions

What are the recommended tools or frameworks for developing VSCode extensions, and can Flutter be used to create the UI components of a VSCode extension?

VSCode extensions are typically developed using JavaScript or TypeScript, as they interact with the VSCode API.