# How to provide for base tag href related url #189214

Tags: flutter, webview, vscode-extensions

### Introduction

I'm trying to create a UI in VS Code using Flutter Web

### Question

I have a question about how I can set the **base** **href** via `vscode-webview-resource` and the `uuid` that is assigned there like [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/98542).

I used the **asWebViewUrl** function as in this [example](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-guides/webview#loading-local-content).

But when I set the value for **base href** here, I get an HTTP (see below) address, although the example says that in debug mode I will get a **vscode-resource**

```html
<base href='https://file+.vscode-resource.vscode-cdn.net/Users...' />
```

Therefore, I get this error:
[image]

If you help me, then you will help [him](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76669862/create-vscode-extension-using-flutter))

### Env

- VS Code Version: 1.80.2
- OS Version: Apple M1 Pro, Ventura 13.4

### Test case

Steps to Reproduce:

1. Clone [repo](https://github.com/shigomany/vscode-extension-webview-flutter)
2. `npm i`
3. In VS Code launch `Run Extension`
4. Open DevTools in VS Code
5. Cmd + Shift + P -> Tap `ARB Part`.

I expected see Flutter Counter in WebView